# What is the best way to pass an object by reference in JavaScript without modifying it

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters, pass-by-reference

I studied that Javascript passes objects by 'pass by reference' to functions. When those objects are mutated/updated inside a function, then it affects the original object. This is clear!

```
let obj = {
 a: 5
};

function test(obj) {
  // Creating a copy of the object to avoid modifying the original
  obj = { ...obj };


 obj.a = 7;
}

test(obj);

console.log(obj.a); // 5
```

If I want to ensure that the original object is not modified, I create a copy of it before making changes in the function. Is this the best way, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: NB: There is no *pass-by-reference* in JavaScript. Objects *are* references.

Comment: "*If I want to ensure that the original object is not modified, is the best way to create a copy of it before making changes in the function?*" and "*What is the best way to pass an object by reference?*" seem to be asking opposite things

Comment: Yes your are right, but what about my code? is this ok?

Comment: @Programmer you can still change nested object properties

Comment: so I should do deep copy, but it is ok to copy then pass the function, or do copy inside function?

Comment: @Programmer copying manually in all functions is error prone, you need some automatic solution, like i've suggested, i'll fix it to make automatic copying

Comment: ok I will wait, but why did you delete your comment :/

Comment: "*What is the best way?*" - that very much depends on the concrete use case. There are many tools to do this (freezing, proxies, copying at call site, copying inside the function,  passing only getters instead of the object itself, type declarations and compile-time checks, …), you should have them in your toolbox and know when to use them. There is no single best "catch-all" solution for this, it always depends.

Comment: Your copy is shallow, so that doesn't really guarantee what you want. Deep copying objects is *expensive* and *verbose*, so generally in practice you would weigh the costs associated with doing that against the need, so the ball is back in your court: how *badly* do you need to the original to be *guaranteed* to not be mutated? Can you get by with a warning (say the way React.js does for state and props)?